# Option to connect to WiFi disappeared after upgrading

Tags: wireless, updates, laptop, lubuntu, firmware

I installed Lubuntu on to my Presario V5000 today off my old 12.04 disk. I installed all the updates then upgraded to 12.10 I was hooked up to an Ethernet cable to update it and before I saw firmware missing under the card so I didn't think much of it after the upgrade when it disapeared so I installed the Broadcam driver for it and it still wasn't there so I would like to know if anyone knows how I could fix my wireless card.

Comment: I recently got it to say the enable wireless checkbox under the enable networking but the option is blocked to check

Comment: try `rfkill unblock all`